# Ruby On Rails: Convert a path in a string to a recursive Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hash, path

Is somebody able to suggest me a way to do this ? ( all is in the subject :D )

what I want is using a "path" and tranform it as a suit of sub key,

e.g. :  I have that params:    path =  "earth/animal/human/men/young/"     value = "martin"
          and I want :

```
  `Global_hash = { earth => { human => { men => { young => "martin"
                                                }
                                       }
                            }
                 }`
```

path =  "earth/animal/human/men/old/"      value = "John"
  and I want :

```
 Global_hash = { earth => { human => { men => { young => "martin",
                                                old   =>  "John" 
                                         }
                                }
                     }
          }
```

add an other

path =  "earth/animal/human/women/old/"      value = "Eve"
  and I want :

```
`Global_hash = { earth => { human => { men   => { young => "martin",
                                                  old      =>  "John"
                                                },
                                       women => { old => "Eve"
                                                }
                                     }
                          }
               }
```

`

The final goal is a way to produce yml file with 2 parameters :
the path and the value

the exemple produces : 
`

```
earth:
  animal:
    human:
      men:    
        young: "martin"
        old: "John"
      women:
        old: "Eve"
```

`
it will allow us to have a yml file with all object  sort by sections thanks to their path.

Thanks per advance

Answer (score 5):

```
path = 'earth/animal/human/men/young/'
value = 'martin'
path.split('/').reverse.reduce(value){ |r, e| {e.to_sym => r} }
```

Comment: thanks your code was very nice but the our friend who send the comments after yours fit more with my needs.
Have you any idea to export it in YML/YAML format ? YAML module I use to load YAML file into Hash var seams to not have function allowing us to do the reverse process.

Answer (score 1):

Functional recursive approach:

```
def insert(hash, path, value)
  head, *tail = path
  if tail.empty?
    hash.merge(head => value)
  else
    h = insert(hash[head] || {}, tail, value)
    hash.merge(head => hash.has_key?(head) ? hash[head].merge(h) : h)
  end
end

h1 = insert({}, "animal/human/women/old".split("/"), "Eve")
# {"animal"=>{"human"=>{"women"=>{"old"=>"Eve"}}}}

h2 = insert(h1, "animal/human/men/old".split("/"), "Adam")
# {"animal"=>{"human"=>{"women"=>{"old"=>"Eve"}, 
#                       "men"=>{"old"=>"Adam"}}}}

h3 = insert(h2, "animal/chimpanzee/smart".split("/"), "Caesar")
# {"animal"=>{"human"=>{"women"=>{"old"=>"Eve"}, 
#                       "men"=>{"old"=>"Adam"}}, 
#             "chimpanzee"=>{"smart"=>"Caesar"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for code lines it was very helpfull
Have you any idea to export it in YML/YAML format ?
YAML module I use to load YAML file into Hash var seams to not have function allowing us to do the reverse process.

Comment: > YAML.dump({:a => 1})
 => "---\n:a: 1\n"